# How do you write 'plus equals' in Lua for a vim setting?

Tags: lua, neovim

How does `set mouse+=a` translate to the equivalent Lua Neovim setting?

Comment: `mouse = mouse + a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vim.opt.mouse` returns a mouse option object.

You can use `Option:append(value)` to append a string value to an option like this.

```lua
-- These are equivalent
vim.opt.mouse:append('a')
vim.opt.mouse = vim.opt.mouse + 'a'
```

Learn more in `:h vim.opt:append()`

There is also a `vim.o.mouse`, which returns the option as a string. You can also append a string value to it using `..`.

```lua
vim.o.mouse = vim.o.mouse .. 'a'
```

Answer (score 4):

From the neovim docs: https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#lua-vim-options

> To replicate the behavior of |:set+=|, use:
>
> ```
>    -- vim.opt supports appending options via the "+" operator
>    vim.opt.wildignore = vim.opt.wildignore + { "*.pyc", "node_modules" }
>
>    -- or using the `:append(...)` method
>    vim.opt.wildignore:append { "*.pyc", "node_modules" }
> ```
>
> To replicate the behavior of |:set^=|, use:
>
> ```
>    -- vim.opt supports prepending options via the "^" operator
>    vim.opt.wildignore = vim.opt.wildignore ^ { "new_first_value" }
>
>    -- or using the `:prepend(...)` method
>    vim.opt.wildignore:prepend { "new_first_value" }
> ```
>
> To replicate the behavior of |:set-=|, use:
>
> ```
>    -- vim.opt supports removing options via the "-" operator
>    vim.opt.wildignore = vim.opt.wildignore - { "node_modules" }
>
>    -- or using the `:remove(...)` method
>    vim.opt.wildignore:remove { "node_modules" }
> ```

Comment: Weirdly, `vim.o.` doesn't work with append, you have to use the more verbose `vim.opt.`

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, there is no `+=` operator. The equivalent to

```
set mouse += a
```

in Lua would be:

```
mouse = mouse + a
```